# Как реализовать эту программу в Python-е?

Tags: python

Дан набор из N не­от­ри­ца­тель­ных целых чисел, мень­ших 1000. Для каж­до­го числа вы­чис­ля­ет­ся сумма цифр его де­ся­тич­ной за­пи­си. Не­об­хо­ди­мо опре­де­лить, какая сумма цифр чаще всего встре­ча­ет­ся у чисел этого на­бо­ра. Если таких сумм не­сколь­ко, нужно вы­ве­сти наи­мень­шую из них. На­пи­ши­те эф­фек­тив­ную по вре­ме­ни и по па­мя­ти про­грам­му для ре­ше­ния этой за­да­чи. Про­грам­ма счи­та­ет­ся эф­фек­тив­ной по вре­ме­ни, если при уве­ли­че­нии ко­ли­че­ства ис­ход­ных чисел N в k раз время ра­бо­ты про­грам­мы уве­ли­чи­ва­ет­ся не более чем в k раз. Про­грам­ма счи­та­ет­ся эф­фек­тив­ной по па­мя­ти, если па­мять, не­об­хо­ди­мая для хра­не­ния всех пе­ре­мен­ных про­грам­мы, не пре­вы­ша­ет од­но­го ки­ло­бай­та и не уве­ли­чи­ва­ет­ся с ро­стом N.

Мак­си­маль­ная оцен­ка за пра­виль­ную (не со­дер­жа­щую син­так­си­че­ских оши­бок и да­ю­щую пра­виль­ный ответ при любых до­пу­сти­мых вход­ных дан­ных) про­грам­му, эф­фек­тив­ную по вре­ме­ни и по па­мя­ти, — 4 балла.

Мак­си­маль­ная оцен­ка за пра­виль­ную про­грам­му, эф­фек­тив­ную толь­ко по вре­ме­ни или толь­ко по па­мя­ти, — 3 балла.

Мак­си­маль­ная оцен­ка за пра­виль­ную про­грам­му, не удо­вле­тво­ря­ю­щую тре­бо­ва­ни­ям эф­фек­тив­но­сти, — 2 балла.

Вы мо­же­те сдать одну или две про­грам­мы ре­ше­ния за­да­чи. Если Вы сда­ди­те две про­грам­мы, каж­дая из них будет оце­ни­вать­ся не­за­ви­си­мо от дру­гой, ито­го­вой ста­нет бо́льшая из двух оце­нок. Перед тек­стом про­грам­мы крат­ко опи­ши­те ал­го­ритм ре­ше­ния. Ука­жи­те ис­поль­зо­ван­ный язык про­грам­ми­ро­ва­ния и его вер­сию.

Comment: Очевидно, что раз числа неотрицательны и не превышают 1000, то суммы цифр могут быть только от нуля до 27 (9+9+9). А дальше всё просто - создаёте дополнительный список sums длинной 28 элементов, инициализируете его нулями, итерируетесь по исходной последовательности, для каждого её элемента вычисляете сумму цифр s, и делаете sums[s]+=1. Алгоритм линейный по времени и константный по дополнительной памяти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну что же вы? Разбивайте задачу на части и пишите код для каждой из них.

> Дан набор из N не­от­ри­ца­тель­ных целых чисел, мень­ших 1000. Для каж­до­го числа вы­чис­ля­ет­ся сумма цифр его де­ся­тич­ной за­пи­си.

```py
def digit_sum(number: str) -> int:
    return sum(map(int, number))
```

---

> Не­об­хо­ди­мо опре­де­лить, какая сумма цифр чаще всего встре­ча­ет­ся у чисел этого на­бо­ра.

Находим количества всех сумм:

```py
def get_counts(numbers: List[str]) -> List[int]:
    counts = [0] * 28
    for v in numbers:
        counts[digit_sum(v)] += 1
    return counts
```

Т.к на входе числа менее тысячи, то наибольшая сумма = 9+9+9, наименьшая 0, итого 28 возможных вариантов, каждому из которых соответствует своя позиция в списке, а в значении хранится количество соответствующих сумм.

Далее выбираем наиболее частую сумму с наименьшим значением:

```py
def min_most_freq(counts: List[int]) -> int:
    best_i = -1
    best_v = -1
    for i, v in enumerate(counts):
        if v > best_v:
            best_i, best_v = i, v
    return best_i
```

> Если таких сумм не­сколь­ко, нужно вы­ве­сти наи­мень­шую из них.

Это достигается тем, что алгоритм обрабатывает значения от меньших к большим, а новые суммы с частотой, равной текущей наибольшей, отвергаются.

---

> На­пи­ши­те эф­фек­тив­ную по вре­ме­ни и по па­мя­ти про­грам­му для ре­ше­ния этой за­да­чи. Про­грам­ма счи­та­ет­ся эф­фек­тив­ной по вре­ме­ни, если при уве­ли­че­нии ко­ли­че­ства ис­ход­ных чисел N в k раз время ра­бо­ты про­грам­мы уве­ли­чи­ва­ет­ся не более чем в k раз. Про­грам­ма счи­та­ет­ся эф­фек­тив­ной по па­мя­ти, если па­мять, не­об­хо­ди­мая для хра­не­ния всех пе­ре­мен­ных про­грам­мы, не пре­вы­ша­ет од­но­го ки­ло­бай­та и не уве­ли­чи­ва­ет­ся с ро­стом N.

Надеюсь, вы знакомы с понятием [сложности алгоритмов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). В условии говорится, что временнáя сложность должна быть не больше линейной, а пространственная – константной. Первое достигается разовым обходом массива входных данных, второе – фиксированным размером `counts`.

---

Пример:

```py
from typing import List

...
# 3 функции выше
...

counts = get_counts(['314', '101', '242', '271', '200', '123', '345', '999'])
print(counts)
result = min_most_freq(counts)
print(result)
```